# Ruby - iterate tasks with files

Tags: ruby, file, loops, batch-processing

I am struggling to iterate tasks with files in Ruby.

(Purpose of the program = every week, I have to save 40 pdf files off the school system containing student scores, then manually compare them to last week's pdfs and update one spreadsheet with every student who has passed their target this week. This is a task for a computer!)

I have converted a pdf file to text, and my program then extracts the correct data from the text files and turns each student into an array [name, score, house group]. It then checks each new array against the data in the csv file, and adds any new results.

My program works on a single pdf file, because I've manually typed in:

```
f = File.open('output\agb summer report.txt')
agb = []
f.each_line do |line|
  agb.push line
end
```

But I have a whole folder of pdf files that I want to run the program on iteratively. I've also had problems when I try to write each result to a new-named file.

I've tried things with variables and code blocks, but I now don't think you can use a variable in that way?

```
Dir.foreach('output') do |ea|
  f = File.open(ea)
  agb = []
  f.each_line do |line|
    agb.push line
  end
end
```

^ This doesn't work. I've also tried exporting the directory names to an array, and doing something like:

```
a.each do |ea|
  var = '\'output\\' + ea + '\''
  f = File.open(var)
  agb = []
  f.each_line do |line|
    agb.push line
  end
end
```

I think I'm fundamentally confused about the sorts of object File and Dir are? I've searched a lot and haven't found a solution yet. I am fairly new to Ruby.

Anyway, I'm sure this can be done - my current backup plan is to copy my program 40 times with different details, but that sounds absurd. Please offer thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. [`Dir.foreach()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) will return the name of the files whereas [`File.open()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-open) is going to want the path. A crude example to illustrate this:

```
directory = 'example_directory'
Dir.foreach(directory) do |file|
  # Assuming Unix style filesystem, skip . and ..
  next if file.start_with? '.'

  # Simply puts the contents
  path = File.join(directory, file)
  puts File.read(path)
end
```

Comment: Better: Use `File.join` to get the full path.

Comment: Cheers! 90% of my beginner Ruby problems seem to be trying to do a thing with the wrong sort of data type, and this would be an example of that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dir.new("./") to get all the files in the current directory

so something like this should work.

```
file_names = Dir.new "./"

file_names.each do |file_name|
  if file_name.end_with? ".txt" 
    f = File.open(file_name)
    agb = []
    f.each_line do |line|
      agb.push line
    end
  end
end
```

btw,  you can just use agb = f.to_a  to convert the file contents into an array were each element is a line from the file.

```
file_names = Dir.new "./"   
file_names.each do |file_name|
  if file_name.end_with? ".txt" 
    f = File.open file_name
    agb = f.to_a
    # do whatever processing you need to do 
  end
end
```

Comment: Oooh fancy. f.to_a is really convenient and easy to understand - I am new to this, so some of the more abstract ways of pushing things in and out of files break my brain.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Globbing for File Lists

You need to use [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to get your list of files. For example, given three PDF files in */tmp/pdf*, you collect them with a glob like so:

```
Dir.glob('/tmp/pdf/*pdf')
# => ["/tmp/pdf/1.pdf", "/tmp/pdf/2.pdf", "/tmp/pdf/3.pdf"]

Dir.glob('/tmp/pdf/*pdf').class
# => Array
```

Once you have a list of filenames, you can iterate over them with something like:

```
Dir.glob('/tmp/pdf/*pdf').each do |pdf|
  text = %x(pdftotext "#{pdf}")
  # do something with your textual data
end
```

If you're on a Windows system, then you might need a gem like pdf-reader or something else from [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/PDF_Processing) that suits you better to actually parse the PDF. Regardless, you should use globbing to create a file list; what you do after that depends on what kind of data the file actually holds. [IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-c-read) and descendants like File#read are good places to start.

### Handling Text Files

If you're dealing with text files rather than PDF files, then something like this will get you started:

```
Dir.glob('/tmp/pdf/*txt').each do |text|
  # Do something with your textual data. In this case, just
  # dump the files to standard output.
  p File.read(text)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you assign your target folder like this `/path/to/your/folder/*.txt` it will only iterate over text files.

```
2.2.0 :009 > target_folder = "/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/*.txt"
 => "/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/*.txt" 
2.2.0 :010 > Dir[target_folder].each do |texts|
2.2.0 :011 >     puts texts
2.2.0 :012?>   end
/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/ex4.txt
/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/ex3.txt
/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/ex2.txt
/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder/ex1.txt
```

iteration over text files is ok

```
2.2.0 :002 > Dir[target_folder].each do |texts|
2.2.0 :003 >     File.open(texts, 'w') {|file| file.write("your content\n")}
2.2.0 :004?>   end
```

results

```
2.2.0 :008 > system ("pwd")
/home/ziya/Desktop/etc3/example_folder
 => true 
2.2.0 :009 > system("for f in *.txt; do cat $f; done")
your content

your content

your content

your content
```